# wsrep_slave_threads and tmpdir space usage

Tags: mariadb, galera

After increasing `wsrep_slave_threads` at Galera nodes I have experienced that the mysql `tmpdir`, which is a ramdisk, was using much more resources. Especially notable during xtrabackup-v2 STTs.

Also strange was that there was a huge discrepancy between `du -s tmpdir` and `df -h tmpdir`. While `du -s tmpdir` showed the directory as empty or only occassionally occupied by some small files, `df -h tmpdir` revealed that the actual usage of the ram risk was getting to 100 percent, what caused databases to crash.

With `lsof tmpdir` you were able to see that there were many deleted files, which has not been freed yet.

```
~ $ lsof /mysql-tmp/
COMMAND     PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE   SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
mysqld    19933 mysql   18u   REG   0,18          0 47695107 /mysql-tmp/ibxVdqUz (deleted)
mysqld    19933 mysql   19u   REG   0,18          0 47695108 /mysql-tmp/ibEEplTO (deleted)
mysqld    19933 mysql   20u   REG   0,18          0 47695109 /mysql-tmp/ibPdHgS3 (deleted)
mysqld    19933 mysql   21u   REG   0,18          0 47695111 /mysql-tmp/ibkwNxvB (deleted)
mysqld    19933 mysql   25u   REG   0,18          0 47695114 /mysql-tmp/ibElJ9YU (deleted)
mysqld    19933 mysql  457u   REG   0,18  134788214 47745791 /mysql-tmp/MLtIcWeR (deleted)
mysqld    19933 mysql  584u   REG   0,18  135912217 49131634 /mysql-tmp/ML28bohx (deleted)
bash      24048  root  cwd    DIR   0,18         80      896 /mysql-tmp
sh        25869 mysql   18u   REG   0,18          0 47695107 /mysql-tmp/ibxVdqUz (deleted)
sh        25869 mysql   19u   REG   0,18          0 47695108 /mysql-tmp/ibEEplTO (deleted)
sh        25869 mysql   20u   REG   0,18          0 47695109 /mysql-tmp/ibPdHgS3 (deleted)
sh        25869 mysql   21u   REG   0,18          0 47695111 /mysql-tmp/ibkwNxvB (deleted)
sh        25869 mysql   25u   REG   0,18          0 47695114 /mysql-tmp/ibElJ9YU (deleted)
sh        25869 mysql  321u   REG   0,18       8192 48945572 /mysql-tmp/#sql_4ddd_1.MAI (deleted)
sh        25869 mysql  414u   REG   0,18       8192 48945573 /mysql-tmp/#sql_4ddd_1.MAD (deleted)
sh        25869 mysql  457u   REG   0,18  134788214 47745791 /mysql-tmp/MLtIcWeR (deleted)
[...]
```

First question: Why does `wsrep_slave_threads` cause `tmpdir` to grow?

Second question: Why is the temporary space not freed occassionally? If the data is deleted, I assume that it is not needed for a later time. Especially ugly, because a full `tmpdir` is causing corrupt databases.